# Как вы очищаете проект от ненужных DLL в Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Например, вы скачали какую-то модную DLL из Nuget, а следом за ней подтянулась тонна других DLL(зависимости).

Потом вы понимаете, что это вам не нужно и хотите это удалить.

Как это оптимально сделать?

Тут возникают следующие проблемы:

1. Как определить, что нужно для конкретной DLL и ненужно для других,
   что бы безболезненно это удалить?
2. Почистить папку от мусора, куда складывает закаченные DLL Nuget.
   Я пробовал удалять через интерфейс VS, но он позволяет удалять только по 1, что неудобно.

Comment: @AK, как я понял, нельзя удалить 1 пакет, что бы грохнуть и все пакеты от которых он зависит. Вот в этом проблема. Например, недавно поставил EF, так он накачал дофига дополнительных пакетов и вот сиди по 1 высчелкивай...

Comment: не оно? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157066/removing-all-unused-references-from-a-project-in-visual-studio-projects

Comment: @NMD, не думаю, что это решение зачистит мне так же папку закачки пакетов с Nuget, а так же зачистит сам файл пакетов. Т.е, если первая проблема и решится, то вторая останется в виде папки забитой, неиспользуемым хламом.

Comment: Сам Nuget умеет делать всякое)) судя по описанию https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/nuget/tools/ps-ref-uninstall-package

Comment: @NMD, а через интерфейс, как я понимаю, это не делается?

Comment: похоже на то, может еще не протащили просто в GUI

Answer (score 7):

Для этого можно поставить Resharper.

Также очень удобно, что когда вы удаляется ссылки на проект и сборки через Resharper, он **также удаляет** все лишних директивы `using`, пространства имён которых содержатся в используемых сборках (что сильно улучшает пользование, так как если удалять вручную ссылки, то также надо не забывать подчищать директивы `using`).

### [Чтобы удалить неиспользуемые ссылки](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Remove_Unused_References.html)

1. В `Solution Explorer` (`Обозреватель решений`), выберите один или несколько проектов, папок решения или корень решения или, другой вариант выбирите узел `References` (`Ссылки`) проекта.
2. Далее одно из двух:

   - Нажмите правой кнопкой мыши по выбранной области и выберите `Refactor → Remove Unused References` (`Рефакторинг → Удалить неиспользуемые ссылки`) в контекстном меню.
   - Нажмите <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> и выберите `Remove Unused References` (`Удалить неиспользуемые ссылки`).

   Откроется диалог `Remove Unused References` (`Удалить неиспользуемые ссылки`).
3. Все ссылки котороые не используются в исходном коде покажутся в древовидное представлении (tree view), сгруппированные по проектам. По умолчанию все ссылки выбраны для удаления. Если необходимо, снимите флажок с тех ссылок, которые хотите оставить.

   [image]
4. Нажмите `Next` (`Далее`), чтобы удалить выбранные ссылки.
5. Вы также можете увидеть все ссылки (и используемые, и неиспользуемые) в выбранной области действия. Чтобы это получилось, нажмите `Analyze Used References` (`Анализировать используемые ссылки`). Ссылки показаны в окне  `Analyze References` (`Анализировать ссылки`), где вы также можете удалить неиспользуемые ссылки. Для большей информации об анализировании ссылок, смотрите [анализ и оптимизация ссылок проекта](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Finding_Usages__Optimizing_References.html).

### Использование Resharper для тех, кто его недолюбливает

Многие сейчас могу возразить, сказав, что он ест кучу ресурсов и будут правы. Если кому интересно, я им пользуюсь так: если зашёл "обросший мохом" проект и надо его подчистить, я его ставлю (если не стоит), или просто запускаю (из приостановленного положения, `Options  → Resharper  → Resume`), делаю кучу массовых рефакторингов, который он позволяет, затем его отключаю, `Options  → Resharper  → Suspend Now` (но не удаляю, так удобней, если вдруг пригодится).

[image]

И он по умолчанию у меня отключен, так как с ним даже на мощнейших ПК работается нешустро. Таким образом вы получаете мощное средство, которое сыграет огромную пользу в час X.

Comment: а он вот честно-честно отключается? В том смысле, что сочетания клавиш и все остальные настройки студии вернуться в исходное? Просто меня откровенно бесит его перегруженный интерфейс и в постоянной работе лично мне он откровенно мешает, но я признаю его пользу при рефакторинге.

Comment: @rdorn Отключается честно-честно в том смысле что он не загружается в память и не ест процессор, это 100%. По поводу настроек, то это легко можно решить сохранив настройки до установки Resharper (импорт настроек, надеюсь вы меня понимаете), затем после установки их экспортировать. Если без импорта. то тут тоже есть способы. По поводу сочетания клавиатуры, то это можно сбросить одной командой `Tools  → Options  → Environment  → Keyboard` и нажать кнопку `Reset`. Остальные вещи там тоже можно настоить буквально за несколько кликов, если надо.

Comment: @rdorn Если совсем с этим проблемы и что-то неясно, можете задать вопрос, а я вам отвечу, пошагово, с картинками. И самые разные способы разжую.

Comment: Спасибо, этого более чем достаточно. Осталось попробовать. Импорт похоже самый надежный вариант, т.к. VS2015 студия сама периодически забывает некоторые свои же настройки, до VS2017 пока руки не доходят

Comment: @rdorn Если что настройки Resharper тоже можно экспортировать в файл, предварительно выбрав самое ненавязчивое поведение. Мне тоже умолчания решарпера не нравятся.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov,Хм...У меня вот Resharper не все неиспользуемые ссылки удаляет. Т.е я открываю и вижу 10 ссылок, которые считаются неиспользуемыми, нажимаю далее не снимая галок, и не все удаеляется.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, Вы частично ответили на вопрос. Вы не описали, как можно массово грохнуть установленные пакеты Нугетом, да так, что бы не гронхуть ничего лишнего. Т.е в итоге, нугете не должно отображаться ненужных папкетов после удаления и папка с закачками нугета недолжна содержать мусор.

Comment: Удалять ненужные юзинги, кстати, умеет и стоковая 2017 студия.

Comment: @VladD Массово во всём решении не умеет. И тут в другом фишка: удаление вместе с неиспользуемыми ссылками. Представьте, вы удаляете сборку стандартным образом, но где-то в решении остаёся `using` из пространств имён лишей сборки. Приходится это делать вручную и во всём решении.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov: Вроде умеет https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKfbk.png. Но да, это без ссылок на сборки.